# error with add-apt-repository

Tags: apt, package-management, ppa

I tried to add a ppa and y got the message here after. The ppa is not added, i.e. not in /etc/apt/sources.list.d.

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository -d ppa:fenics-packages/fenics
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1363, in _conn_request
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1139, in connect
    address_info = socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/socket.py", line 955, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 364, in <module>
    sys.exit(0 if addaptrepo.main() else 1)
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 347, in main
    shortcut = handler(source, **shortcut_params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/shortcuts.py", line 40, in shortcut_handler
    return handler(shortcut, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 82, in __init__
    if self.lpppa.publish_debug_symbols:
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 120, in lpppa
    self._lpppa = self.lpteam.getPPAByName(name=self.ppaname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 107, in lpteam
    self._lpteam = self.lp.people(self.teamname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 98, in lp
    self._lp = login_func("%s.%s" % (self.__module__, self.__class__.__name__),
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/launchpadlib/launchpad.py", line 494, in login_anonymously
    return cls(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/launchpadlib/launchpad.py", line 230, in __init__
    super(Launchpad, self).__init__(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lazr/restfulclient/resource.py", line 477, in __init__
    self._browser.get(root_resource), 'application/json')
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lazr/restfulclient/_browser.py", line 439, in get
    response, content = self._request(url, extra_headers=headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lazr/restfulclient/_browser.py", line 389, in _request
    response, content = self._request_and_retry(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lazr/restfulclient/_browser.py", line 359, in _request_and_retry
    response, content = self._connection.request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1725, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/launchpadlib/launchpad.py", line 144, in _request
    response, content = super(LaunchpadOAuthAwareHttp, self)._request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lazr/restfulclient/_browser.py", line 184, in _request
    return super(RestfulHttp, self)._request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1441, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1370, in _conn_request
    raise ServerNotFoundError("Unable to find the server at %s" % conn.host)
httplib2.error.ServerNotFoundError: Unable to find the server at api.launchpad.test
```

Notice it is not due the ppa since I have tried several other ppa. Moreover, I also tried to purge software-properties-common, and it has not fixed the problem.

Here are the info of my system :

```
$ lsb_release -rd
Description: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release: 22.04
```

Here is the version of the package:

```
$ apt-cache policy software-properties-common
software-properties-common:
  Installé : 0.99.22.7
  Candidat : 0.99.22.7
 Table de version :
 *** 0.99.22.7 500
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     0.99.22 500
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages
```

Here are version of other packages on which software-properties-common depends on:

```
$ apt-cache policy python3-software-properties
python3-software-properties:
  Installé : 0.99.22.7
  Candidat : 0.99.22.7
 Table de version :
 *** 0.99.22.7 500
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     0.99.22 500
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages

$ apt-cache policy python-apt-common
python-apt-common:
  Installé : 2.4.0ubuntu1
  Candidat : 2.4.0ubuntu1
 Table de version :
 *** 2.4.0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.3.0ubuntu2 500
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages
```

Comment: Have you made any changes to your *default* python3?  eg. Errors like what you're seeing (*along with other tools that require a working python3*) are expected if you've changed defaults; is `python3 -V` showing the correct result for a 22.04.2 system?

Comment: No changes to my knowledge.
`$ python3 -VV
Python 3.10.6 (main, May 29 2023, 11:10:38) [GCC 11.3.0]`

Answer (score 1):

There was a bug raised which has since been resolved. Please see [their official message](https://ubuntu.social/@launchpadstatus/110594525393361192)

> We've reverted the relevant part of frontend configuration and this is now fixed.  However, if you're still seeing programs failing with errors that mention api.launchpad.test, then you'll need to run `rm -rf ~/.launchpadlib/api.launchpad.net/cache/` and try again.  (Unfortunately recovering automatically from bad cache data lifetime is hard!)

Comment: This answer would have been better if you'd copy/pasted the text from those *Launchpad Status* account posts.... (*I can't see Colin Watson or whomever else can post to the ML would mind; esp. if you credit the source*) .  This site prefers not answers to that require you to read another page that provides notice of the fix & workaround if it didn't fix the issue for you.

Comment: This has done the trick ! I will just add that the folder to remove is in /root, so the command is `rm -rf /root/.launchpadlib/api.launchpad.net/cache/`

Answer (score 0):

Try going with:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-launchpadlib
```

Solved the issue for me.